# How to compute inside object there was array inside the I need to add all?

Tags: javascript

does anyone know how to compute inside grades? I tried use function but not working and i also try   const grades = 'grades'; but still not computing inside grades anyone know the algo of this?

```
  const students = [{
      name: 'Khelly',
      grades: [78, 92, 85, 88]
      },
      {
          name: 'Jared',
          grades: [90, 86, 94, 89]
      },
      {
          name: 'Alio',
          grades: [72, 84, 80, 76]
      },
      {
          name: 'Alvin',
          grades: [68, 72, 65, 80]
    }];
    
    
    const grades = 'grades';
    function calculateCar(array, property) {
      const total = array.reduce((accumulator, object) => {
        return accumulator + object[grades];
      }, 0)
      return total;
    }
    
    const totalCar = calculateCar(students, 'price');
    console.log(calculateCar);
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to add the items. You can do it this way:

```js
  const students = [
      {
          name: 'Khelly',
          grades: [78, 92, 85, 88]
      },
      {
          name: 'Jared',
          grades: [90, 86, 94, 89]
      },
      {
          name: 'Alio',
          grades: [72, 84, 80, 76]
      },
      {
          name: 'Alvin',
          grades: [68, 72, 65, 80]
      }
];
console.log(students.map(item => {
    let total = 0;
    item.grades.forEach(item => total += item);
    return {name: item.name, grades: total};
}));
```

`.map()` projects, using your array items as input and the result of a function with them as outputs. Inside this `.map()`, we sum `item.grades` and return an object with the proper name and `total` as the value for `grades`.

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentioned the desired result as `[ { name: 'Khelly', grades:95}, { name: 'Jared', grades: 87}, { name: 'Alio', grades: 83}, { name: 'Alvin', grades:82} ]`. So just map the array and calculate sum of grades for each student:

```js
const students=[{name:"Khelly",grades:[78,92,85,88]},{name:"Jared",grades:[90,86,94,89]},{name:"Alio",grades:[72,84,80,76]},{name:"Alvin",grades:[68,72,65,80]}];

const grades = students.map(student => ({...student, grades: student.grades.reduce((r, grade) => r + grade)}));

console.log(grades);
```